# use of regex to find a pattern and get the result

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I really have a hard time with Regex expressions and I'm trying to do a string search and get the value that was found with regex.

At this point I'm using a lot of `.indexOf()` and `.substring()` and so on to achieve what I want, but it seems pretty costly.

So, to describe what I want I'll start of by stating that I know that the following part : `subject.replace(/\bwid=([^&]*)/g, "wid=1234");` ; would go through the string, find that `wid=` in the string and it will replace whatever it's after until it meets first `&` with whatever I need.

Now what I want it's a bit different, I have this pattern : `/q=/` ; which is found somewhere in the string. My value would be after the `=` and before the `/` : `/q=some_value_here/` ; I need to search for something like that in the string and instead of replacing it, just get the value from there so I can use it.

I have tried `/\b!q=/=([^/]*)/`, but obviously I need to escape something in there and change it, because it doesn't quite work :) Could anyone help out ? And on this subject of regex, where could I find some good tutorials on how to use it ?

**EDIT :** String example : `http://rgr-ashley.vertica.dk/us/en-us/search#!/q=/test`

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ should help you get started, and a google for online regex tester yields a few helpful sites for testing your regex like http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: Can you give an example of the input string ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this one :

```
var matches = str.match(/\!\/q=\/([^/]*)/)
```

The value is at index `1` of `matches`.

You need to escape the `/` (as a `/` ends the regex literal) and I don't know why you've put the `!` and the second `=`.

Comment: the `!` was because it's withing a hash, the hashbang, but I can ignore that.

Comment: If you give an example of the input string, it would be easy to design the right regex.

Comment: Just added one in the question desc

Comment: Great, but this looks for `!/q= ...`, or it is not important where in the string the `/q=/` is after the `!` ? It's not necessary to be right after, it can be a few indexes after and something else can be right after `!`.

Comment: Then remove the `\!` or use `\!.*?\/q=\/([^/]*)/`.